# Studio plugin to view contents of XAP file

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, plugins, xap

Has anyone come across a plugin (or similar) for Studio that will allow me to view the contents within a XAP file?
I'm just after a way to view the file list quickly rather than having to.. browse to folder, rename to zip and open. *(I'm not asking for a xap decompiler or anything like silverlightspy, purely a seemless decompressor)*

Ideally, just double clicking the `ClientBin\myapp.xap` from the solution browser to view the contents.

Rather than writing a plugin myself, I am hoping that someone already has one, or a simple technique to save me the time.

*[As background, I like to monitor xap sizes by keeping a close eye on what's being included in the xap]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jut right click your xap file, choose open with WINRAR or other decompresseor exe you have, don't forget to set it to default. I guess this is the quickest way to accomplish what you want instead of writing some VS plugin yourself.

Regards,
Allen

Comment: I think the important thing to know is that a XAP file is just a ZIP file.

Comment: Allen, thank you for your prompt and spot on reply. I'm a bit embarrassed that the obvious didn’t come to me. Looking too hard to see the solution staring me in the face.!
Thanks mate.